# Is it okay for a class method to reflect a passive action on the object, or must it always reflect active action?

Tags: java, function, class, oop, methods

I was wondering about the proper way to write class methods. I am pretty sure that my first class here follows proper coding standards because the methods reflect things that an instance of the class might do.

```
class Turkey {
    public void hunt() {
        System.out.println("Hunting for insects...");
    }
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating plants, fruits, berries and insects...");
    }
}
```

However, would it be okay for a class method to reflect an action of which the class instance is a recipient instead?

```
class Turkey {
    public void hunt() {
        System.out.println("Hunting turkey...");
    }
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Happy Thanksgiving!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Fine if they were named clearly.

Comment: I tend to make my choices based on what is pragmatic. As long as it's clear and not insane...

Comment: This is probably too broad a question for Stack Overflow - you could maybe try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ . As a short answer, normally the method should be an action that the class is responsible for the behaviour of; so if the turkey has a choice of how to `beHunted` then that should be a method on the `Turkey` class, but if the hunter has a choice of how to `hunt` a turkey, then that should be a method on the `Hunter` class. In your example, there isn't really any behaviour other than trivial printing to the console, so there is no good answer.